# No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/ruby-2.2.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, version, rvm

I am trying to install ruby 2.2.3, currently I have 1.8.7 installed. It shows below error message:

```
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/ruby-2.2.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more         
information on binary rubies.
You requested building with '/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in 
your path.
```

I have tried multiple ways to install it, including below commands, but it doesn't work at all.

```
rvm get head
rvm autolibs enable
rvm use --install 1.9.2
bundle install
```

And

```
rvm requirements
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Any particular reason you want that version of Ruby?  The latest Ruby is 2.5.1 and 2.2.X is [no longer officially supported](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2018/06/20/support-of-ruby-2-2-has-ended/).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Ruby binaries are precompiled for some popular operating systems. This significantly reduces installation time.

Obviously, this is not your case and for your OS `rvm` suggests to compile Ruby files from source code. But compilation fails due to

```
You requested building with '/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path.
```

So you need to install `gcc-4.2` compiler to continue. There are a lot of recipes in the web how to do so, from homebrew to macports, for example:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118830/install-gcc-to-mac-via-terminal

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am not able to install gcc-4.2 since my mac os version is too new (High Sierra) and there is no usable gcc.